# Проблема с плеером на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, mediaplayer

Есть самопальный плеер на JavaScript, если я добавляю второй элемент `<audio>`, то он работает лишь с первым источником, игнорируя другой, то есть переключения не происходит.

Как воспроизводимый audio останавливать и выполнять play на другом? Учитывая что `id` един.

В итоге, хотелось бы чтобы он легко смог переключаться между треками.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<audio id="mytrack" controls>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="mytrack" controls>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<nav>
    <div id="defaultbar">
        <div id="progressBar"></div>        
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button  type="button" id="playButton"</button>
        <button type="button" id="muteButton"></button>
        <span id="currentTime">0:00</span>
        <span id="fullDuration">0:00</span>
    </div>  
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
var mytrack = document.getElementById('mytrack');
var playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
var muteButton = document.getElementById('muteButton');

var duration = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');

var barSize = 640;
var bar = document.getElementById("defaultbar");
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');

mytrack.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", changeDuration);

function changeDuration() {
    var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.duration/60);
    var seconds = pad(parseInt(mytrack.duration%60));
    duration.innerHTML = minutes+":"+seconds;
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
playbut.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
muteButton.addEventListener('click', muteOrUnmute,false);
bar.addEventListener('click', clickedBar, false);

function playOrPause() {
    if(!mytrack.paused && !mytrack.ended) {
            mytrack.pause();
        playButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://pp.vk.me/c637617/v637617622/1dd8c/UEl9FgLZ8Uk.jpg)';
    window.clearInterval(updateTime);
    }
    else {
        mytrack.play();
        playButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://pp.vk.me/c637617/v637617622/1dd85/CC4adfFPVDA.jpg)';
        updateTime = setInterval(update , 1);
    }
}

function muteOrUnmute() {
    if(mytrack.muted == true) {
        mytrack.muted = false;
        muteButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://pp.vk.me/c637617/v637617622/1dd93/VaNlI7pWMkE.jpg)';
    }
    else {
        mytrack.muted = true;
        muteButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://pp.vk.me/c637617/v637617622/1dd93/VaNlI7pWMkE.jpg)';
    }
}

function update() {
    if(!mytrack.ended) {
        var playedMinutes = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime/60);
        var playedSeconds = pad(parseInt(mytrack.currentTime%60));
        currentTime.innerHTML =playedMinutes + ':' + playedSeconds;

        var size = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime*barSize/mytrack.duration);
        progressBar.style.width = size + 'px';
    }
    else {
        currentTime.innerHTML = "0.00";
        playButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://pp.vk.me/c637617/v637617622/1dd8c/UEl9FgLZ8Uk.jpg)';

        progressBar.style.width = '0px';
        window.clearInterval(updateTime);
    }
}

function clickedBar(e) {
    if(!mytrack.ended) {
        var mouseX = e.pageX - bar.offsetLeft;
        var newtime = mouseX*mytrack.duration/barSize;

        mytrack.currentTime = newtime;
        progressBar.style.width =  mouseX + 'px';
    }
}

function pad(d) {
    return (d <10) ? '0' + d.toString() : d.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя использовать два одинаковых ID на одной странице, отсюда и ошибка. ID - один, класс - может повторяться.

Comment: Теоретически конечно можно (но не нужно!). Самое интересное то, что ошибок это никаких не вызовет. Но при обращении к элементу по его ID всегда будет браться самый первый элемент с этим ID, соответственно до "повторок" просто не дойдет. А по спецификации да, нельзя. Тут вы в точку.